# SVN Tortoise messed up because all workingcopy files were deleted, new ones were pasted in and checked out / added. What now?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So as the title says, Tortoise is messed up because a working folder contained various of files. These files were however outdated and deleted by a user and then the up to date files were copied back in the working folder. Next the user added, committed and after a update that the files had to be updated he also did that. Well things went wrong ;)

Now in the working copy there are various files with exclamation marks, question marks and just files that are extra added with .r0 , .r986 extension. The question is how to fix this mess?

The best thing would be to delete the entire folder and create a new one but how? (I'm also not a SVN expert)

Answer (score 0):

You can revert (go back) to a revision where things were in a good state, or just undo the specific commit that added all the messy files. With TortoiseSVN, right click -> Revert changes from this revision.

If after all, you want to delete, right click, Delete. Via console/command line:

`svn merge -r X:X-1`, where X is the culprit commit, and X-1 just a revision before the mess.

```
svn delete -r folder
```